# How to use AuthServiceProvider from routes.php in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

Seen the laravel AuthServiceProvider functionalities, https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization, I'd need to filter routes based upon user permissions, like:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'can','action'="user.admin"], function () {
    Route::any('/', ['as' => 'user.index', 'uses' => 'UserController@index']);
    Route::any('{id}', ['as' => 'user.show', 'uses' => 'UserController@show']);
});
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should see this [doc](http://heera.it/laravel-5-1-x-acl-middleware#.Vt1VvnV957g). Here is a good explanation of ACL in laravel 5 .

http://heera.it/laravel-5-1-x-acl-middleware#.Vt1VvnV957g